# Can't use minikube ingress on local machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I've been trying to follow the [ingress-minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) tutorial but with some modifications. Instead of using `kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080` I created deployment.yaml file as fallows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/change-cause: "image updated to latest"
  name: web
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-app
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

I have set up my service as NodePort, though I've also tried ClusterIP. Here is the configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: web
  name: web
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32222
  selector:
    app: web
```

My ingress yaml is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

After applying all configurations, I noticed that the endpoint in my ingress is `192.168.139.2` and the host is `hello-world.info` As I'm running it locally, I added `192.168.139.2 hello-world.info` to my `/etc/hosts`.

When I check the IP with `minikube ip`, it returns `192.168.139.2`, which matches the IP of the ingress endpoint.

However, when I try to access the welcome page at `http://hello-world.info`, I receive an error that the website is unavailable and there's a connection timeout.

Creating a tunnel with `minikube service web --url` does allow me to access the welcome page, but I'd like to access it locally via ingress, not through directly tunneling to the service.

What do I need to change to be able to connect to my webpage locally using only ingress?

Comment: Check your default NGINX Ingress Controller is not supported and maybe did some updates and Nginx is not compatible with your older version of their cluster.

Comment: My NGINX Ingress Controller is running a compatible version, but I encountered a different example https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/  where I need to use the Minikube tunnel. After setting that up, I gained access to the Ingress in Kubernetes, which is installed on a Docker container. However, I cannot use the Minikube IP for connections because it is an IP inside the Docker container, not on my local machine

Comment: **minikube addons enable ingress** enables the minikube implementation of the [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube). After the addon is enabled, please run **minikube tunnel** and your ingress resources would be available at "127.0.0.1". Also try setting up the Ingress controller in **Kind**.